# Calculate the total sizes of a file in a row

Tags: php

I have a table in filenames and sizes, however, I have no clue how to calculate the total file size in the row...
Please find the example below:

```
filename File size

file1———2098656

file2———5637484

file3———6788977
```

I need to calculate file size as a loop

Comment: Do you mean you want to ADD UP all the File Sizes for all the rows in this table

Comment: show us the relevant code, what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have given more info about how it's stored in the code (e.g. array structure?). Or maybe you are thinking about an SQL approach, or...? In case we're talking about an array, you can loop on it and increment a variable:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($data as $row) {
  $total += $row['file_size']; // or whatever it's called
}
echo "Total is: $total";
```